# How to integrate weather api in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Please anyone help me how to integrate a api in wordpress api is in json formate

https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Iam using this code but im not able to display temprature

```
 <?php 

 $url = 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';

$response = wp_remote_get( $url  );
if( is_array($response) ) {
  $header = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
  $body = $response['body']; // use the content

  print_r(($body));

}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Abu,

1. Put the  code somewhere useful in wordpress so you can use the wp_remote_get
2. Understand the structure of the response (just putting the url in firefox address bar will give JSON structure
3. Understand that you receiving JSON, and decode it http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
4. Find the temperature in the structure and use that as per code example below.   Slightly freak out when you see the number but then ...
5. Read the API FAQ https://openweathermap.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1996493-switching-between-temperature-units  and realise the number is in Kelvin

I'll leave it to you to research how to request temp in Celcius or Fahrenheit

```
function show_temp() {

 $url = 'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';

$response = wp_remote_get( $url  );
if( is_array($response) ) {
  $header = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
  $body = $response['body']; // use the content
  $resp = json_decode($body);
  echo 'The temp in Kelvin is: '.$resp->main->temp;
  echo '<pre>'.print_r($resp, true).'</pre>';
}
}

add_shortcode ('show_temp', 'show_temp');
```